# How to store the URL's and Titles of a list of posts under same label into a String array in Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

The question I have is, how to store the URL's and Titles of the posts under the **one and the same label** into a String array.

Suppose I have a number of posts under the label Action URL
And supposedly the posts Titles and URL's under that **Category** or **Label** are :

and some others...
I want 2 arrays like `var pTitle` and `var pURL` 
and I want it to store like this

```
pTitle[0]=Comic 1 Chapter 1  
pTitle[1]=Comic 1 Chapter 2  
pTitle[2]=Comic 2 Chapter 1  

pURL[0]=url 
pURL[1]=url  
pURL[2]=url
```

Please Help by providing a Code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should be able to achieve what you require -

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
  <script>
    var URLArray = <b:eval expr='data:posts map (post =&gt; post.url)'/>;
    var TitleArray = <b:eval expr='data:posts map (post =&gt; post.title)'/>;
  </script>
</b:if>
```

The `b:if` condition only loads this code on Label pages. Also, to make  it work, place this inside the `Blog` gadget (Add it inside the `<b:includable id='main' var='top'>` tag. Don't include it inside the `b:loop` tag for posts or it will get repeated multiple times on a page)

Comment: Can you help me in this question @Prayag  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929419/next-and-prev-buttons-for-blogger-theme

Comment: Can I use a variable also instead of data:blog.searchLabel?