# How to match and point to a particular data in array in Blogger

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

As I asked in a previous question and I got a good and working answer :
 [How to store the URL's and Titles of a list of posts under same label into a String array in Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017303/how-to-store-the-urls-and-titles-of-a-list-of-posts-under-same-label-into-a-str/43017581#43017581)

Now I want to know how to make a variable point or get the index number of the particular url.

Suppose I use `var cURL="<data:post.url>"` to store the URL of the post I am currently browsing on the blog into `cURL` variable.

Supposedly the blog post I have currently opened happens to be:

> **SITEURL**

And the variable `cURL` stores this URL. I want a code to search and match this URL in a array which I have stored a number of URL's

Now if the value of `cURL` is as already above

If the array is `var URLArray` and its data with index happens to be:

As highlighted in bold above, the URL in `URLArray[2]` matches the URL stored in `cURL`.
Now I want this Index number `2` stored in a variable.
Since blogger doesn't allow normal java `for` loops, I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript method [findIndex()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) for this purpose. The code for same will be of the form

```
<script>
  var URLArray = <b:eval expr='data:posts map (post =&gt; post.url)'/>;
  var cURL = "<data:post.url/>";

  function IndexFinder(element,index) {
    return element == cURL
  }

  var storeIndex = URLArray.findIndex(IndexFinder);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!!

Comment: I wanted to confirm, doesn't the variable element and index need declaration? and when calling the function IndexFinder, isn't parameters needed to be given, like `var storeIndex = URLArray.findIndex(IndexFinder(10,20));` or something like that?

Comment: The way `findIndex` works is a little different, it accepts a function (in our example `IndexFinder` ) with a specific set of parameters. Refer to the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex to understand it better

Comment: And can you please help me in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211943/navigating-next-and-prev-posts-under-same-labels-in-blogger

Answer (score 1):

To get index number through loop use index attribute as in the following example :

```
<b:loop index='i' values='data:posts' var='post'>

    <data:i/> : <data:post.url/>

</b:loop>
```

**Notes :**

- `i` can be any name you choose.
- Loop index starts from zero.

**Javascript version :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var URLArray = [];
    <b:loop index='i' values='data:posts' var='post'>
        URLArray[<data:i/>] = <data:post.url/>;
    </b:loop>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!