# Getting the list of Posts under the same labels of the Currently opened Post In Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

As I had already asked in
[How to store the URL's and Titles of a list of posts under same label into a String array in Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017303/how-to-store-the-urls-and-titles-of-a-list-of-posts-under-same-label-into-a-str/43017581#43017581)

And the answer given was

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>
  <script>
    var URLArray = <b:eval expr='data:posts map (post =&gt; post.url)'/>;
    var TitleArray = <b:eval expr='data:posts map (post =&gt; post.title)'/>;
  </script>
</b:if>
```

Now I want is,
Suppose I have some posts under the same labels as the post I have currently opened, I want those posts to be stored in an array.

**Wait**, Let me explain first how my blog is made by me and how it works.

The blog which I have is blogger blog .It is blog for comics.

Supposedly I have some chapters of a manga named **Dungeon Seeker**.
I have put the posts/chapter I posted under this manga with the label same as the name of the manga as **Dungeon Seeker** and some other labels which will be their genres like Action ,Adventure etc.

At the starting you can see the labels are **Action,Drama,Dungeon Seeker,Fantasy**.

Suppose I use a variable and make it work like the snippet below :

```
var getTitle="<data:post.title/>";
var getTag=getTitle.substring(0, getTitle.lastIndexOf(" Chapter"));
```

Now, Supposedly the post I am currently browsing is **"Dungeon Seeker Chapter 1"** and due to the code above `getTag` will store the value as **"Dungeon Seeker"**, which is the same as the label name it is put in.

**Now I want a code to store all the posts under the label name same as the `getTag`.**

I have no problem if the method is different, but I want it to have the same concept as above and achieve what I want.

I am not sure how this might help but use the code in the below link if necessary only.
https://pastebin.com/taURKjLF
The link is for **RELATED POSTS WIDGET** for Blogger. I am linking to it since the topic I have posted is nearly related to the idea of how the widget code is made.