# Navigating Next And Prev Posts Under Same Labels in Blogger

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

For starters I want you to read
[Next and Prev Buttons for Blogger Theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929419/next-and-prev-buttons-for-blogger-theme/)

Understood the concept of what I want? Then let's continue with my question :

Now I have the code that was already embedded to the theme for next and prev buttons and they were :

```
<nav class='op-pagi'>
<a class='blog-pager-older-link' expr:href='data:olderPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-older-link&quot;' expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'><i class='fa fa-angle-left'/> Prev</a>
<a class='blog-pager-newer-link' expr:href='data:newerPageUrl' expr:id='data:widget.instanceId + &quot;_blog-pager-newer-link&quot;' expr:title='data:newerPageTitle'> Next <i class='fa fa-angle-right'/></a>
</nav>
```

And Using the questions I had asked before like :
[How to store the URL's and Titles of a list of posts under same label into a String array in Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43017303/how-to-store-the-urls-and-titles-of-a-list-of-posts-under-same-label-into-a-str/43017581#43017581)
AND
[How to match and point to a particular data in array in Blogger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43154669/how-to-match-and-point-to-a-particular-data-in-array-in-blogger/43184792#43184792)

I made a code myself :

```
<script>
//<![CDATA[

<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>

  var URLArray = <b:eval expr='data:posts map (post =&gt; post.url)'/>;
  var TitleArray = <b:eval expr='data:posts map (post =&gt; post.title)'/>;  

var cURL = "<data:post.url/>";
var gTitle = "<data:post.title>";
function IndexFinder(element,index) {
   return element == cURL
}
function IndexFinderT(element,index){
   return element == gTitle;
}
var sU = URLArray.findIndex(IndexFinder);
var sT = TitleArray.findIndex(IndexFinderT);

function prevURL(){
    var prevU=URLArray[sU-1];
return prevU;
}
function prevTitle(){
    var prevT=TitleArray[sT-1];
return prevT;
}
function nextURL(){
    var nextU=URLArray[sU+1];
return nextU;
}
function nextTitle(){
    var nextT=TitleArray[sT+1];
return nextT;
}

</b:if>
//]]>
</script>
```

Now I tried Using the code which I showed first for next and prev button by changing  `expr:href='data:olderPageUrl'` **to** `expr:href='prevURL()'`
and the same for Title also
`expr:title='data:olderPageTitle'` **to** `expr:title='prevTitle()'`
but didn't work.

Can you please tell me where I went wrong and how to make it work?

**Note:** I'm using **CDATA** Tag for no particular reason, just put it there thinking it might help in someway. I didn't understand its exact usage even when I searched on google. If it's causing any problem please mention it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both `prevURL()` and `prevTitle()` are JavaScript functions and not Blogger data tags, you don't need to use the `expr` in front of the attribute.

You will instead need to modify the functions as follows -

```
function prevURL(){
    var prevU=URLArray[sU-1];
    document.querySelector('.blog-pager-older-link').href = prevU;
}

function prevTitle(){
    var prevT=TitleArray[sT-1];
    document.querySelector('.blog-pager-older-link').title = prevT;
}
```

and similarly for the next page links. No need to change the HTML of the page.

Also as *Bassam* mentioned in the other answer. Don't wrap the JavaScript in `CDATA` directive otherwise, the XML parser that Blogger uses will completely ignore the script block and no data tag will get evaluated

Comment: Prayag, did you understand how and what I wanted to achieve? even after the changes the code doesn't work how I wanted it to. You have been a lot of help to me....so can you please help me till the end?

Comment: Can I use `onclick='functionname();'`

Comment: Yes, you can use `onclick` attribute as well if you don't want to modify the script. I will look into the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42929419/next-and-prev-buttons-for-blogger-theme/ and see if I can come up with a solution to resolve it

Comment: https://pastebin.com/taURKjLF  The link is for Related Posts Code. Since the code I want is or might be nearly related to this.

Comment: Prayag do you know any website where I can upload JS files and use it in my blog?

Comment: please help me in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43591877/use-of-blogger-lightbox-in-custom-template

Answer (score 1):

Using CDATA prevents blogger XML parser from interpreting data tags like `<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>`

Remove `//<![CDATA[` and `//]]>` from the code or use them after blogger tags :

```
<script>

<b:if cond='data:blog.searchLabel'>

var URLArray = <b:eval expr='data:posts map (post =&gt; post.url)'/>;
var TitleArray = <b:eval expr='data:posts map (post =&gt; post.title)'/>;  
var cURL = "<data:post.url/>";
var gTitle = "<data:post.title>";

//<![CDATA[

function IndexFinder(element,index) {
   return element == cURL
}
function IndexFinderT(element,index){
   return element == gTitle;
}
var sU = URLArray.findIndex(IndexFinder);
var sT = TitleArray.findIndex(IndexFinderT);

function prevURL(){
    var prevU=URLArray[sU-1];
return prevU;
}
function prevTitle(){
    var prevT=TitleArray[sT-1];
return prevT;
}
function nextURL(){
    var nextU=URLArray[sU+1];
return nextU;
}
function nextTitle(){
    var nextT=TitleArray[sT+1];
return nextT;
}

//]]>

</b:if>

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can paste this code in the posting widget

```
<b:includable id='pager_chapter' var='type'>
<b:if expr:cond='data:post.labels any (l =&gt; l.name != data:type.name)'>
  <script type='text/javascript'>var selectchap = false;</script>
</b:if>
<b:if expr:cond='data:post.labels any (l =&gt; l.name == data:type.name)'>
  <script type='text/javascript'>var selectchap = true;</script>
</b:if>
<b:loop index='i' values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
  <b:if cond='data:i == 0'>
  <div class='pager-js rounded' id='pager-js'>
  <div class='_prev' id='prevjs'><a class='pager-js-nolink'><span class='material-icons' style='font-size:2.5rem;'>chevron_left</span></a></div>
  <div class='_index' id='indexjs'><a class='pager-js-nolink'><span class='material-icons' style='font-size:2.5rem;'>list</span></a></div>
  <div class='_next' id='nextjs'><a class='pager-js-nolink'><span class='material-icons' style='font-size:2.5rem;'>chevron_right</span></a></div>
  </div>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    var postPrev = &quot;<span class='material-icons' style='font-size:2.5rem;'>chevron_left</span>&quot;;
    var postNext = &quot;<span class='material-icons' style='font-size:2.5rem;'>chevron_right</span>&quot;;
    var postIndex = &quot;<span class='material-icons' style='font-size:2.5rem;'>list</span>&quot;;
    var postID = <data:post.id/>;
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    if(selectchap==false){
      var yktocs=function(data){
        var i=0;
        for(;
        i<data.feed.entry.length;
        i++){
          var j=0;
          for(;
          j<data.feed.entry[i].link.length;
          j++){
            if("alternate"==data.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel){
              var entityUrl=data.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
              break
            }
          }
          document.getElementById("indexjs").innerHTML="<a href='"+entityUrl+"' title='Index Novel'>"+postIndex+"</a>"
        }
      };
      var ykpager=function(data){
        var node={
          postlist:[]
        };
        var i=0;
        for(;
        i<data.feed.entry.length;
        i++){
          var j=0;
          for(;
          j<data.feed.entry[i].link.length;
          j++){
            if("alternate"==data.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel){
              var murl=data.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
              break
            }
          }
          var videoId=data.feed.entry[i].id.$t;
          var CAPTURE_ID=videoId.substr(51,19);node.postlist.push({
            url:murl,id:CAPTURE_ID
          })
        }var v=node.postlist.findIndex((timeline_mode)=>{
          return timeline_mode.id==postID
        });
        var id=v+1;
        var cbs=node.postlist[id];
        if(null!=cbs){var g=Object.values(cbs)[0];
          var lnkDiv=document.getElementById("prevjs");
          lnkDiv.innerHTML="<a href='"+g+"' title='Chapter Sebelumnya'>"+postPrev+"</a>"
        }
        var q=v-1;
        var val=node.postlist[q];
        if(null!=val){
          var k=Object.values(val)[0];
          lnkDiv=document.getElementById("nextjs");
          lnkDiv.innerHTML="<a href='"+k+"' title='Chapter Selanjutnya'>"+postNext+"</a>"
        }
      }
    }
    else{document.write("<style>.pager-js{display:none;}</style>")
  };
    /*]]>*/
  </script>
  <script defer='defer' expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/summary/-/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=ykpager&amp;max-results=99999999&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
  <script defer='defer' expr:src='&quot;/feeds/posts/summary/-/&quot; + data:type.name + &quot;/&quot; + data:label.name + &quot;?orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=yktocs&amp;max-results=1&quot;' type='text/javascript'/>
</b:if>
</b:loop>
</b:includable>
```

And paste code below After `<data:post.body/>`

```
<b:include data='{name : &quot;Novel&quot;}' name='pager_chapter'/>
```

You can read full tutorial [How To Make Next and Prev Button By Label on Blogger](https://www.nurhidayat.web.id/2019/11/tombol-nextprev-otomatis-blogger.html)