# Use of Blogger Lightbox in Custom Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger

I have a blogger blog.
I want a code which will help me get the blogger lightbox working.

I even tried putting

```
<script src='http://www.blogger.com/static/v1/jsbin/2321381434-lbx__fr.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

code as I check a post in Blogger forum's but still didn't get it. 
Please help me with the code!

Here is the link for my blogger template : 
https://pastebin.com/J0S89qbr

Answer (score 1):

Login to Blogger. From your dashboard go to Settings>Posts comments and sharing then select 'Yes' for 'Showcase images with Lightbox' option. 
See if this helps.

Comment: Just so you know, I have been using blogger since about 8 years. I know all the options and have tried those and then only asked for help here :D

Comment: @yashas123 you can follow this tutorial here:    [link](http://lamazerone.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-fix-lightbox-effect-for-blogger.html)

Comment: the code `<!--Start lightbox -->

<script 
src='http://lightbox-blogger.googlecode.com/files/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
<script 
src='http://lightbox-blogger.googlecode.com/files/lightbox.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<!--End lightbox scripts -->` won't work since the links for the JS files are dead. When I open the links, it says 404 Error!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is happening because the Blogger's default JavaScript has been commented out. Due to which the Lightbox CSS & JavaScript are not getting loaded on the page. Look for the following code in your theme XML -

```
&lt;!-- 
</body>
--&gt;&lt;/body&gt;
```

and replace it with the following code

```
</body>
```

Comment: As I thought you are amazing. It was such a simple thing and I didn't notice LOL. Thanks for the help :D. Can we become friends in FB or G+ I want more in future if possible :D